# Nifi :Nan instead of attribute value

Tags: apache-nifi

there are  several  subjects  i  am interested in:

1. What  type is  nifi attribute?  i  use  count  attribute in my executeScript  processor   with expression like  it 
   isn't  defined anywhere except 
   executeScript processor (this:`${count:replaceNull(${count:toNumber():plus(1):toString()})}`
   and  it  doesn'  work   what  should  i  change  to  make  this expression  work
2. During  cron Scheduling  how  does   processor  works?  for  example  if i want to start  processor in  every  5  minute and i have expression  like  this  inside${count:replaceNull(${count:toNumber():plus(1):toString()})} it  means  that  count  will  increase in every 20 minutes  or it  doesn't metter?

Answer (score 0):

NiFi is data agnostic unless you want to make/shift data type.

**Note:** - don`t use **count**, use other attribute name, **count** it seems to be a reserved word.

Also **null + 'value' = null** (*always*) so your expression is working fine **:)**.

**The logic you are looking for is : (i belive)**

```
${count:replaceNull(${count:toNumber():plus(1):toString()})}
```

*If count is null give a value of count + 1 (null + 1 = null)*

**toNumber()/toString()** - they don`t serve any purpose here.

- So what you need is a sister attribute, create it when you instantiate the initial count attribute .

and you code should be :

```
${i:replaceNull(${c})}
```

**Where:**
- if attribute **i** is null replace with attribute **c**

For Question number 2 - are you in a loop ? give more info !